# How to record mixed string and number results in a loop?

Tags: matlab

For example,

```
x = zeros(3,1);
y = [10.tt 1; 
      2.tt 1; 
      3.tt 1];
"y is 'xlsread' into mat file". 
for i = 1:5
y (i,1), which = [10.tt; 2.tt; 3.tt]
```

How can I record `y(i, 1)` value into `x`? `x` will equal `[10.tt; 2.tt; 3.tt]`?

"10.tt ....." those numbers only show the data is a string and number combination.

Comment: ... sorry, but I'm not sure I understand what your code snippet is supposed to mean, and what exactly you want to do. What is `10.tt` for example? What is that unfinished loop at the end of your code?

Comment: try to record y(i,1) to a new matrix say x... the data in y is string and number combination.... my questions is how to record those kind of data? I want the end of the loop will be.... x(i,1) = y(i,1), end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/cell.html) or a [struct](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/struct.html):

```
y = [{'abc', 2}; {'def', 3}]
```